# Sort data.table unique values (r language)

Tags: r

I have my table(input):

```
  user_id   is_Leaver  age
1 Helen     yes        25
2 Helen     yes        25
3 Helen     yes        25
4 Rob       no         31
5 Rob       no         31
```

I need to have table with unique logs(Output):

```
  user_id   is_Leaver  age
1 Helen     yes        25
2 Rob       no         31
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please consider searching the site for answers before posting a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this :

let's say your dataframe = df;

```
df <- unique(df)
```

It should do the trick.

Comment: So easy!! Thx it works perfect!